# How do I implement my own static Empty or Zero field properly

Tags: c#, class-design

I have a class, this class can be empty. This class has only public properties of type String. When this class is in an empty state, that means that all properties have the value of String.Empty.

1) With a public static **field**, the properties of Class.Empty can be modified.

2) I don't see that a public static **property** getter should return a new empty object (set all fields to Empty *manually*) every time. I consider that bad practice.

3) An alternate solution is to implement your own *Class.**IsNullOrEmpty**(Class obj)*.

4) A *non-static* public boolean property *obj.**IsEmpty***.

In the *other class* where *this class* is being used, the property will never be null. The *other class* is returned from a method (of yet another class,) which properly initializes it.

The only case the property might be null, is if it's newed outside that method, which then causes it to be in an invalid state anyway.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1 and 2 conflict, basically.

Either your type is immutable, in which case you can return a reference to the same instance every time... or it's mutable, in which case you *have* to return a reference to a new object each time.

The reason `string.Empty` is fine is precisely because `string` is immutable.

Does your type *have* to be mutable?

EDIT: Based on your comment, it sounds like the properties shouldn't have setters at all. Instead, the values should be passed into the constructor, and stored in readonly fields.

At that point your type is immutable, so you can expose either a public field or property which always returns the same value, i.e.

```
private static readonly MyType empty = new MyType("", ""); // Or whatever
public static MyType Empty { get { return empty; } }
```

or

```
public static readonly MyType Empty = new MyType("", "");
```

You don't need to worry about anyone setting any properties, because you haven't got any setters...

Comment: I once the properties are set, they should never change. So the answer is no, right?

Comment: This is true, that is how I initially set the properties, via the constructor. Unfortunately I forgot to mention that the type will be serialized with XmlSerializer. To my knowledge, that requires public get/setters for all serialized properties. However, if I implement IXmlSerializable (this is a small class destined not to change), I do not require public setters. Correct? If this class were to change, I not only have to change/add fields, but also the strings in the IXmlSerializable implementations?

Comment: Ah. I'm afraid I'm far from an expert in XML serialization, but that sounds like it might work...

Comment: Wouldn't that be a breaking change if Empty's value was changed between implementations? Usually serializing the empty constant would not be required.

Comment: @Guard: Potentially, yes. There are all kinds of difficult situations to consider when it comes to versioning and serialization, regardless of technology :)

Comment: The special gotcha here is that an object that references the static Empty and is then serialized and deserialized now references a copy of the static, so a reference comparison will fail.  This sometimes bites people who serialize DBNull and test for it by reference instead of class.